How does corruption work in the framework of the act-potency divide?
In aristotelean and thomistic philosophy, becoming is explained as a potency being reduced to act. E.g. I have the potency to write this post, I actualise it, now it is here.
This is simple. But how does it work the other way around? How does corruption work?
E.g.: burning a hat.
A hat is a substantial form, which is also called a first act. I have often seen the problem of corruption evaded over explaining it as a »substantial transformation«: The hat form merely changes into ash form.
But this explanation fails if you admit that the substantial form of the hat is an act that is now totally gone / has ceased to exist. How can this be? Is the act reduced to potency? Does it simply cease to exist? If so, how? Or am I wrong in saying a substantial form is an act?

I think you're probably wrong to conflate a substance with an act. On what basis do you connect the two? Probably more relevant is Aristotle's discussion of mixture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Generation_and_Corruption

Your interpretation is close to a common one, "the form of an entity, as introduced in the Metaphysics... is identical to its characteristic function or activity" says Austin, for example. But "exists" does not literally apply to a form, only to a matter-form compound. Matter is what remains through change, including generation and corruption, potentiality
to become something else. Corruption consists in the matter ceasing its activity, but describing that as "ceasing to exist" can only be metaphoric.

You may be interested in Aquinas's commentary, 57 on mutuality of generation and corruption:"The corruption of this is the generation of something else, and vice versa... a thing is per se corrupted into a being in potency, which indeed is now subject to another form, according to which it is a being in act, and to the privation of the previous form, with respect to which it is now non-being in act... that which is corrupted becomes non-being, yet something else remains, namely, that which has been generated."

@Conifold thank you for your answer, i found it most helpful. I do have a follow up question for clarification: you say »corruption consists in the matter ceasing its activity«, but that this could only be called »ceasing to exist« metaphorically. so do matter and form only »exist« virtualiter? bc if they did exist realiter, the »ceasing to exist« would not be in a metaphorical sense.

Matter separately and form separately are only aspects of a substance, the only thing that exists proper. They are separated only by intellect, but cannot be "pulled apart" in reality, although they can be transferred separately to another carrier substance. For example, the shape of the statue does not really "exist" apart from the statue, but can be thought of separately or physically copied in asbestos.

@Conifold okay understood this solved it for me. the paper by Austin is also very good. than you <3
